# C4389 signed/unsigned mismatch only for x86 compilation c++

Tags: c++, std, compiler-warnings

I am seeing a C4389: "'==': signed/unsigned mismatch" compiler warning when I execute the following code in Visual Studio using the x86 compiler using a warning level of 4.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void functionA()
{
    std::vector<int> x(10);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    {
        if (std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), i) != x.end())
        continue;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this happens and how I can resolve this?

Here is a link https://godbolt.org/z/81v3d5asP to the online compiler where you can observe this problem.

Comment: You need to cast `i` in the `find` call to an `int` to match the elements in the vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared `x` as a vector of `int` – but the value you are looking for in the call to `std::find` (the `i` variable) is a `size_t`. That is an unsigned type, hence the warning.

One way to fix this is to cast `i` to an `int` in the call:

```cpp
if (std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), static_cast<int>(i)) != x.end())
```

Another option (depending on your use case) would be to declare `x` as a vector of an *unsigned* integer type:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned int> x(10);
```